# Extract filebeat prospector 'fileds' used from all attributes definitions (ruby based)

Tags: ruby, attributes, filebeat

I'm currently adding filebeat support for services we provide; 
For every service we have several log files I would like to track;
I have 1 common filebeat recipe and I'm distinguishing between the different services' logs in different attributes .rb files; 
In those I have a separate definition per log;

All definitions have the same "fileds" configuration; 
Can I add it to someplace to be used by all configurations?

My structure:

```
  cookbooks    
    common
      recipes
        filebeat.rb   
    services
      attributes
        service1.rb
        service2.rb
```

The content of servicesX.rb has the following definitions:

```
access_log = {
    'paths' => ['TBD'],
    'input_type' => 'log',
    'fields' => {
      'hostname' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["hostname"],
      'customer' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["layers"][0],
      'internal_ip' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["private_ip"],
      'ec2id' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["aws_instance_id"],
      'os' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["os"],
      'instance_type' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["instance_type"]        },
      'fields_under_root' => true
}


audit_log = {
    'paths' => ['TBD'],
    'input_type' => 'log',
    'fields' => {
      'hostname' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["hostname"],
      'customer' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["layers"][0],
      'internal_ip' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["private_ip"],
      'ec2id' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["aws_instance_id"],
      'os' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["os"],
      'instance_type' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["instance_type"]
      },
      'fields_under_root' => true
}
```

How can I extract

```
'fields' => {
  'hostname' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["hostname"],
  'customer' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["layers"][0],
  'internal_ip' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["private_ip"],
  'ec2id' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["aws_instance_id"],
  'os' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["os"],
  'instance_type' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["instance_type"]
```

Someplace in the same file (servicesX.rb) so to be used by all log files definitions?

Note: I'm a ruby novice :/

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

After feedback and clarification in comments below, OP seems to want to `DRY` the code and re-use a `fields` definition.

Simplest is to store it in a variable and then use that:

```
fields = {
  'hostname' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["hostname"],
  'customer' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["layers"][0],
  'internal_ip' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["private_ip"],
  'ec2id' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["aws_instance_id"],
  'os' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["os"],
  'instance_type' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["instance_type"]
}

audit_log = {
  'paths' => ['TBD'],
  'input_type' => 'log',
  'fields' => fields
}
```

This, however, may cause issues with how `node` is set. It really depends on the flow of the rest of your script. In chef (assuming this is about chef) a `node` is the context on which the script runs, so setting the `fields` too early might give issues when that `node` is used much later:

```
fields = { hostname: node["opsworks"]["instance"]["hostname"] }
# ... do lots of stuff, like fetching, preparing, connecting and whatnot.
fields # now contains the `node` values as set before connecting etc.
```

If this is an issue, a better option would be to define a method that returns the fields from a passed-in node:

```
def fields(node)
  {
    'hostname' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["hostname"],
    'customer' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["layers"][0],
    'internal_ip' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["private_ip"],
    'ec2id' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["aws_instance_id"],
    'os' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["os"],
    'instance_type' => node["opsworks"]["instance"]["instance_type"]
  }
 end
```

Or, cleaned up:

```
def fields(node)
  instance = node["opsworks"]["instance"]
  {
    hostname:      instance["hostname"],
    customer:      instance["layers"][0],
    internal_ip:   instance["private_ip"],
    ec2id:         instance["aws_instance_id"],
    os:            instance["os"],
    instance_type: instance["instance_type"]
  }
 end
```

Then use that function:

```
audit_log = {
  'paths' => ['TBD'],
  'input_type' => 'log',
  'fields' => fields(node)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response . I want to use all fields parameters as they are set, in every log definition, without copy-paste the same code (for those fields parameters )definition for every log;  Thus I thought there might be a way to extract them at the beginning of the the file (or else) and just call them inside every log definition;

Comment: I don't understand what you want, then. Could you reword your question to show more clearly what data you start with and what data you want to end up with?

Comment: apologies; sure, here it goes:  I would like to be able to extract the whole "'fields'" section outside of the separate logs definitions. Maybe at the beginning of the .rb file?  and inside the logs definitions, I want to just call for them. As it seems I will add parameters in 'fields' and I don't want to copy-paste the same thing for every log file definition; Hope this helps?

Comment: So, to be certain: you want to define the fields *once* and then use that definition in the rest of the places?

Comment: yep :)  I found   https://erichelgeson.github.io/blog/2014/02/02/attributes-and-string-interpolation-in-chef/  .. Not sure if I'm the right path

Answer (score 0):

After my research: The benefits of the implementation does not justify the time invested;
Leaving it;